# apache on windows network - can't connect to external ip from in network

Tags: apache, codeigniter, networking, nat, windows-networking

I created an AMP web application that was originally going to be served from a traditional 3rd party host.

As we finished up, the client decided to host it internally, on a server in their office network.  The application is only meant to be available to staff members, but those staff members will often be off-site.  I had no involvement in setting up their network, which uses at least one server running windows server 2003.  The client machines I saw were XP.

I set up Apache, MySQL and PHP on the server 2003 machine, and installed the application.  The application is built on the CodeIgniter framework, so I set the base_url to the internal IP (192.168...), and we tested from within the network.  Everything worked fine.

Next, we asked their network guy to open port 80 for apache.  I set the base_url to the external IP, and tested from my home (using the external IP as the web address), and it works fine.

However, when attempting to access the application using the external IP from within the network, they're unable to connect.  I can reset the base_url to the network IP, and they can access it using the network IP, but then it the application fails when connecting externally (since the base_url, used throughout the application, is pointing to the internal IP).

It suppose I could let CodeIgniter determine the base_url (by leaving the variable as an empty string), but would rather figure out why the external IP fails in-network, and try to correct that.

The server we're using is not dedicated to the AMP stack (in fact, it has at least one other application broadcasting to the internet that must have been using IIS, as well as an FTP server used for office scanners), so I suppose there might be some conflicts there.

I know very little about windows networking.  A quick search suggested this might be because of NAT, but didn't offer a work-around.

Their network guy has no suggestions, and said that everything should be fine.

Is it possible to have users inside the network access the Apache server using the external IP, and if so, what needs to happen to enable that?

TYIA

Comment: Good question, but honestly, this should be a [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't Apache related, nor is it CI related. It's often impossible to reach the external IP address from within the network.

Frankly, I don't know exactly why that is. I do know that it's related to how NAT (Network Address Translation) works or at least how it's implemented.

For a detailed overview of *why* this is, you should ask this question on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com). If you're simply a programmer who has to deal with it, accept that NAT usually works only from inside to outside and outside to inside, but not inside to inside.

You already mentioned one of the solutions in your question - don't use `base_url`. You could also simply run the server on an external IP address (not your company IP, but let's say a datacenter or something).

Comment: "If you're simply a programmer who has to deal with it" - yep!  And I put the CI and Apache tags just because the question made reference to both, and I thought that was important, but you're right, it's a networking / server question.  Anyways, I just set base_url to an empty string and it seems to be fine.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Your client's NAT router is configured to forward packets arriving on its external interface for its external IP with port `80` to the internal machine, port `80`, after re-writing the source and destination IP addresses in the packets.

From within the network, attempts to connect to the external IP address will be routed to the *default route* on the machines, the router's *internal* interface. This interface is *not* configured to forward packets *back into the network*.

Configure the application to listen on all IP addresses. Make sure that the server knows that the clients know it under several hostnames -- the internal IP address and the external IP address.

You might be able to re-write the NAT firewall rules on the router to perform the port forwarding for the internal interface as well, but off-the-shell equipment common in homes and small businesses do *not* make this task easy. More expensive gear (or home-built *BSD/Linux router machines) can do this without much effort, but it would needlessly add traffic to the router.