# Can't connect client to server (python)

Tags: python, client

Server :

```
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 8000
```

Client :

```
HOST = '#MyIPAddress'  (found on http://www.ip-adress.com/)
PORT = 8000
```

Client fails connecting to the server. It works if client.HOST = 'localhost' to but that's not the point. I forwarded my router to open that port. I want it to work over the internet. I tried stuff like https://pagekite.net/ but I couldn't make it work.

I would like to see any complete "hello world" example wich would send "hello world" through the internet between two clients. Either server runs on my computer or on a hosted platform I would like to see a full concrete example.

Comment: what code/modules have you tried?

Comment: Firewalls on the computers?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8696689/113848) explains why this doesn't work.

Comment: All firewalls disabled

Comment: If they're different hosts, try having the server bind to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your server and client are located at the same machine, then just
   set `client.HOST = 'localhost'` as you said.
2. If your server and client are located at different machines, you
   should try ping through each other.
3. If your server is behind an NAT device, you need to enable  port
   forwarding (such as upnp, dmz etc.) in order to make sure tcp
   request from your client could reach your server first. What your
   said sounds more like a network issue than a programming issue. Hope
   this could help you.